# service account unable to run python script that imports from arcgis.gis

Tags: python, arcgis

Would anyone know why a service account would be unable to run a python script if it includes this statement?

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
```

The script can be executed by me as an admin, but not by the service account. The service account has read/list/execute on "D:\Program Files". the library is located in "D:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro"

Here's the text of the script:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import logging

try:
    now = datetime.now()
    logFile= 'User_Results\Logs\Import_Log_' + now.strftime('%Y%m%d') + '.log'
    logging.basicConfig(filename=logFile, level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info('Beginning Execution: ' + str(now))
except Exception as e:
    logging.error('Error - ' + str(e))
    raise
```

The python script simply writes a log file. If I remove "from arcgis.gis import GIS", the script works. If I run the script as an admin, the script works as well even with the "from arcgis.gis import GIS" line.

The event viewer has this information:

```
Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 3.7.9150.1013, time stamp: 0x5f726282
Faulting module name: _arcgisscripting.pyd, version: 12.7.0.26828, time stamp: 0x5fc9f663
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000ff5fc6
Faulting process id: 0x3db0
Faulting application start time: 0x01da668eb5044c6f
Faulting application path: D:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\python.exe
Faulting module path: D:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgisscripting\_arcgisscripting.pyd
Report Id: 9650d5ec-420c-4e15-af02-da03bae87e05
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```